# Timeout error during subscription to push notifications

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, aws-api-gateway

When I try to subscribe to push notifications and use my API Gateway endpoint as notifications url

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
-d '{
     "changeType": "Created", 
     "expirationDateTime": "2020-09-04T14:48:27.391Z", 
     "notificationUrl": "AWS_API_GATEWAY/dev/webhooks",
     "resource": "/me/mailfolders('\''inbox'\'')/messages"}' \
-X POST "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions"
```

I get the request timeout error ()

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Subscription validation request timed out.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-09-02T14:51:26",
      "request-id": "2d4c31ae-af4c-40cb-a40e-d7ec4281ddfc"
    }
  }
}
```

A few weeks ago the same request worked without any issues. Now only 1 out of ~5 is successful.
However when I do the same request but put my ngrok as notification url (which is simple reverse proxy to THE VERY SAME AwsApiGateway `ngrok -> ruby proxy stuff -> aws api gateway`) it works perfectly

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
-d '{
     "changeType": "Created", 
     "expirationDateTime": "2020-09-04T14:48:27.391Z", 
     "notificationUrl": "NGROK_PROXY/dev/webhooks",
     "resource": "/me/mailfolders('\''inbox'\'')/messages"}' \
-X POST "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions"
```

It looks like some Outlook put some limits on my ApiGateway endpoint. I have not found any explanations of such behaviour in docs though.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were encountering this exact issue for our graph subscription endpoint (AWS API Gateway backed by a NodeJS Lambda) and were struggling to track down the exact cause.

We tried numerous ways to debug what was going on including:

- Checking Lambda execution logs - nothing for failed attempts.
- API Gateway logs - nothing logged.
- API Gateway 'Access Logging' - again nothing.
- Calling the endpoint from VMs running in different Azure regions - worked without issue.

We came to a similar conclusion to you - the Microsoft Graph API is (intentionally or unintentionally) blocking subscription requests to AWS API Gateway endpoints.

Our solution was to add a Route53 managed domain in front of the API Gateway endpoint. Since adding this we have had zero failures due to 'timeout's.

Comment: Thanks for answer Michael! Yeah, we also ended up adding custom domain managed by Route53